# Orchard CMS issue with alternative shape summary - razor

Tags: orchardcms

I have created an alternative shape via the Shape tracer module using the Bootstrap theme.  I have a number of fields I created for this type. The custom type I created is called "BooksForSale". I can display the Author using the following code:

```
<p>@Model.ContentItem.BooksForSale.Author.Value</p>
```

Thats fine.

However, I wanted to display the body for this type (this part was added) and display only the first 150 characters. I used the following:

```
@{ 
    Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentPart.ContentItem;
    string bodyHtml = Model.Html.ToString();
    var body = new HtmlString(Html.Excerpt(bodyHtml, 500).ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "</p>" + Environment.NewLine + "<p>")); 
}
<div class="post-description">
    <p>@body</p>
</div>
@Html.ItemDisplayLink(T("Read More...").ToString(), contentItem)
```

This crashes because of the Read more line while the author displays fine.

I pulled this from the "Parts.Common.Summary.cshtml" - it works there.

What I want is to display the first 150 characters of the body and have a link "Read More..." display and link to the actual content item.

Not sure anybody can help here but thought I might ask...

SImon

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error message? Anything relevant appearing in your log file?

Comment: What is the filename for your alternative shape?

Answer (score 1):

It would really, really help if you would specify *how* it crashes. Seeing how your first code sample works, I would suspect that you need to replace `Model.ContentPart.ContentItem` by just `Model.ContentItem`. The second line works fine in Parts.Common.Body.Summary.cshtml because there `Model` is the body part. Where you copied that, it may be another part (but you didn't give nearly enough details for me to know: you don't even give the name of the template alternate you created). So what you need to do is cast it to the body part, like this:

```
string bodyHtml = contentItem.As<BodyPart>().Html.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Bertrand,Thanks for writing back.  I have managed to sort out most of this with the help of a friend.  The Projection name is BooksForSale.  As you suggested I did need to change to Model.ContentItem and it has worked. Here is the current code:

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy, i have a similar question:

How do call '@Display.Parts_Comment(Model)' in some shapes that have alternated in Theme/Views?  Actually i want to display the 'CommentForm' part in arbitrary place in alternate file. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. Actually, that is an entirely new question as far as I can tell, and so it should not be asked in a comment.